# View helper methods not included for Devise views in rspec integration/request tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, integration-testing

When I visit my sign in page in a browser everything works fine.

When I visit my sign in page in an rspec integration/request test, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `title' for #<#<Class:0x00000007af9180>:0x00000007af32a8>
```

The title method is used by the view and defined in ApplicationHelper which devise seems to find when using the browser. However, during rspec integration tests, devise is unable to find the helper method.

Is there anything I should be stubbing? It seems wrong to be stubbing in integration tests. Any other ideas?

(This question is not about how to include devise helpers in integration tests. I'm manually filling in the sign in forms to authenticate).

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this, Nathan? I'm having the same issue when using capybara and rspec request specs; if a view involved in the test calls any helper methods, I'll get an exception. In my case, this only happens if I've got guard running; running rspec by hand works. Thanks

Comment: No. I didn't. However, I found that in some cases, spork was causing problems for me (some tests worked when run outside spork).

Comment: Thanks. I did some more testing and found that spork is the culprit. Haven't determined exactly what the issue is, but without spork, it's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/109). (in some cases related to ActiveAdmin https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Use-spork)

[Here](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/pull/140) I found a hack that works for me (REE 1.8.7, Rails 3.1, Capybara, Devise, active_admin).

However, this is not likely to be merged, so I forked spork-rails to [here](https://github.com/chopmo/spork-rails) with that patch applied. And as you probably know I can point my Gemfile to that repo:

```
gem 'spork-rails', :git => "git://github.com/chopmo/spork-rails.git"
```

Not optimal but it gets the job done for now.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this. I tried including your gem in my Gemfile, ran bundle install, then when I ran spork, I get the following error: "undefined method `inject' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
    /home/nathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@OfficeHours/gems/spork-1.0.0rc2/lib/spork/gem_helpers.rb:5:in `latest_specs'".

I'm running 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.

Comment: Chopmo, the issue you mentioned had some new comments recently that helped me solve the problem. For me, it was a conflict with ActiveAdmin - solved with https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Use-spork. I updated your answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chopmo for the fork: it's working! Looking into the Github issue, I think we should be cautious with this hack since there must be something it breaks, but I couldn't figure it yet. BTW, this issue is not related to ActiveAdmin in my project, but I don't know what is yet.

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow up on this, for some reason I wasn't getting SO notifications. But I'm glad to hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using Cucumber when I installed devise:

```
undefined local variable or method `flash_block' for #<#<Class:0x007ffd0a28dae8>:0x007ffd0b2f6d58> (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

I solved it by including the module in `env.rb`

```
Spork.prefork do
  include FlashBlockHelper
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This solved the problem for me (using ApplicationHelper, etc instead).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside /spec/support create devise.rb with this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Make sure your spec_helper.rb includes:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

and that your specs have:

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Comment: This is not a problem with including devise helpers.